# MD5 function not functioning properly

Tags: c++, windows

<strike>This is my current MD5 function. When used on windows 8.1 it always returns a value, but when run on windows 7 it only returns a value about 50% of the time. That is pretty peculiar to me. Any ideas?</strike>

It turns out that it is dodgy on both win7 and win8. Apparently the call to CryptGetHashParam sometimes fails with ERROR_MORE_DATA.

```
std::string MD5(std::string input)
{
    HCRYPTPROV CryptProv;
    HCRYPTHASH CryptHash;
    BYTE BytesHash[33];//!
    DWORD dwHashLen;
    std::string final;

    if (CryptAcquireContext(&CryptProv,NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET))
    {
        if (CryptCreateHash(CryptProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &CryptHash))
        {
            if (CryptHashData(CryptHash, (BYTE*)input.c_str(), input.length(), 0))
            {
                if (CryptGetHashParam(CryptHash, HP_HASHVAL, BytesHash, &dwHashLen, 0))
                {
                    final.clear();
                    std::string hexcharset = "0123456789ABCDEF";

                    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                    {
                        final += hexcharset.substr(((BytesHash[j] >> 4) & 0xF), 1);
                        final += hexcharset.substr(((BytesHash[j]) & 0x0F), 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    CryptDestroyHash(CryptHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(CryptProv, 0);
    return final;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *pp = "derp";
    std::string derp = MD5(std::string(pp));
    printf("%s\n", derp.c_str());
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what does it do instead of returning a value? What are your inputs? What is your compiler? How do you execute the code?

Comment: It just returns an empty string. I'll post the full code calling it in a second.

Comment: Do you use the same compiler for Windows 7 and 8?  What is the processor's bit width for each platform (for example, win7-32 bit, win8 -64 bit)?

Comment: Yes, it's being compiled for Win32 in Visual Studio 2013 and I'm using the same binary for both operating systems.

Comment: You have `if` conditions to check for errors, but you don't actually do anything if one of these conditions fail.  Simple print statements would go a long way here...

Comment: `char *pp = "derp";` This is not legal. Really your main should just look like `int main() { std::cout << MD5("derp") << '\n'; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a fantastic idea: add `else` clauses to those conditions so that you know which one is failing. Put *output* in those clauses so that you can see detail on the error conditions. Then you will know what is wrong with your function.

Comment: Simple, but cheap. :-)  The OP should actually use a debugger.

Comment: Actually his MD5 function _should_ throw the relevant exception when it fails, debugger or no.